Solenoid Economizer circuit
I am putting together a circuit that is supposed to open a solenoid quickly then hold it open with less current so as to reduce heating and potential burning of the coil. The fast opening will be achieved by higher voltage then PWM on 12 volts to hold it. I am speculating that this will also help close the solenoid quickly too as there should be less magnetic saturation to dissipate.
I am all self taught in electronics so I may not have the right verbiage or knowledge to say things in ways you might be used to, so be easy on me if possible .
The circuit consists of three gate drivers with the control signals provided by a PCM in order to control the timing between which mosfet turn on or off at any particular time. It is wanted to be able turn on and off this solenoid quickly and precisely. Unfortunately I can't share too much more as I am not at library to reveal the purpose of this solenoid.
The first prototype I made had 48 volt capacitor to open the solenoid and then when the capacitor was discharged it would drop down to 12 volts to hold it open. But the solenoid would still get quite hot and a few burned out during testing. I would like to limit the overall heating in the whole circuit as it will be sealed in a box with no ventilation so I would prefer to not use any resistors to limit current.
The solenoid can use upwards of 20 amps to open with 48 volts and 5 or so amps to hold on 12 volts. So resistors would dissipate quite a bit more heat then I would be conferrable with. So I thought maybe a PWM signal that if tuned to the right frequency and duty cycle can limit the overall current while still hold it open.
Would anyone be willing to look at my basic schematic and tell be if I made any blunders before I submit the design for PCB manufacturing?

Ok, so I tried to run a simulation of this circuit using the "not so sure it's very accurate" Falstad.com simulator. The above didn't work. It seemed that the PWM side wouldn't trigger if the 48 volt open side was connected to the circuit. Was unstable and unpredictable. So I redrew the circuit with N channel fets in a sort of bootstrap. Not sure if this is a true bootstrap but it did seem to work in the simulation. The signal looked as I would expect but only if I replaced the solenoid with a resistor. Once I put the solenoid or inductor in the signal looked a bit off with a very short turn on time and. I'm guessing its the back emf or ringing or oscillation that makes it look off. And that in a real circuit it might look different.
Here is the new modified schematic. If anyone is willing to point out any flaws or error, or perhaps any improvements that would be appreciated. I am hoping to get an answer if this circuit will work or not, and if not why or ways to improve it. Thanks

I built both circuits last night and neither worked. The first one with P channel fets wouldn't turn off and I was getting 48 V out of the gate on both fets???
The 2nd on wouldn't turn on. Couldn't really tell what the fets where doing. Something I'd get a few pulses and other times nothing

Are you sure your solenoid is rated for continuous duty?

I'm pretty sure it's not continuous duty rated if using straight 12 volts. It won't be on for more then a second or so under normal operation, but even then it builds up heat. If left on for about 5 seconds it will burn the windings. Solenoid can't be changed to another  type as it's integral to the machine and operates high pressure fluid. The manufacturer suggested PWM to reduce total current demand and heating in the coil. So I'm hoping this circuit can achieve the goals

What about just applying the 48V initially and then going to a low duty-cycle PWM of the 48V to hold the solenoid?

(1) What is the nominal actuation voltage? (2) Is it an AC or DC solenoid? (3) Can you share the solenoid model number?

A 48V PWM might work but I think it would have to be so low to reduce heating that it might actually start causing the solenoid to drop out between pulses. These are extremely fast solenoids. Capable of mS precision. So we can't have too low duty cycle or it will start to pull in and out with each pulse

No model number on the solenoid. Old equipment not manufactured anymore. So keeping what we have alive is important. There is no voltage rating that I know of. Just scope captures of an old running driver board that had a 48V pull in spike and a 12V 80kHz 40% duty cycle PWM for holding. This is what I'm trying to replicate

Take in account that P-MOSFET (enhancement) will switch on with VGS negative voltage > VTH. In the first circuit, Q6 will get VGS=-48 V in case gate driver output is 0 V, or VGS=-36 V in case gate driver output is +12 V. This voltage will probably destroy the P-MOSFET, as will be over VGSmax.
With N-MOSFET you can drive the gate with a resistor divider not to rise over VGSmax. This resistor  will limit the current, so it will not be  fast. A Zener maybe be used in 48V path to protect gate. Also see that D3 is at drain side, so V1 can´t go through this path to source or gate.

Regarding second circuit, NMOS Q9 and Q10 will have a significant voltage drop, similar to gate VTH. To switch on properly, you need isolated drivers with a floating power supply or bootstrap voltage.

Thanks for the information. Very helpful. I appreciate you even provided a schematic to try. You are right that in the first circuit the voltage will destroy the P fet. I tried out the circuit over the weekend and sure enough it shorted out the fet and I was getting 48 V out the gate. On the second circuit, it was hard to tell what it was doing but I think it was as you describe with it not turning on all the way and creating a large voltage drop.

As for R1 & R2, are they necessary? It seems like it would be beneficial to draining the gate faster with them not there?  Also, I'm not sure how D1 can work protecting M1 gate from excessive voltage. It's just connected in parallel to R3. Wouldn't it be better to connect D1 to the gate and ground

Ok, so I tried the above circuit and it also shorts out the P mosfets. I end up getting 48 volts coming out of the gate

@Jason Harrison: R2/R3 (and R1/R4 if necessary)  will reduce VGS below max allowed. Calculate 48V*R3/(R2+R3) < VGSmax .

But with M2 off, wouldn't that cause R2 to be floating and useless, thus causing 48 volts to the gate of M1?

@Jason Harrison: with M2 switched off, VGS of M1 will be zero, gate will be discharge by R3. (VGS=voltage gate to source).

Ok, I'll double check my circuit and make sure I didn't mess up anything and try it again
